# System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm currently trying to moq my `Cafe` `Get` method which will throw a `ArgumentNullexception` if the cafe ID is not found.

#### Error

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Cafe
> Non-overridable members (here: Context.get_Cafe) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Is this occurring because moq is unable to handle one of the setup expressions?

#### Unit test

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetCafeByIdAsync_Should_Throw_ArgumentNullException()
{
    var cafe = new List<Cafe>()
    {
        new Cafe { Name = "Hanna", CafeId = 1},
        new Cafe { Name = "Bella", CafeId = 2 }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Cafe>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Cafe>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(cafe.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Cafe>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(cafe.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Cafe>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(cafe.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Cafe>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(cafe.GetEnumerator());

    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
    }).CreateMapper();

    var contextMock = new Mock<Context>();
    contextMock.Setup(x => x.Cafe).Returns(mockSet.Object); //failing here

    var cafeService = new CafeService(contextMock.Object, mapper);

    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => cafeService.Get(2));
}
```

#### SUT

```cs
public async Task<VersionResponse> Get(int cafeId)
{
    var cafe = await _context.Cafe.Where(w => w.CafeId == cafeId).ToResponse().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return new VersionResponse()
    {
        Data = cafe
    };
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use one of the following [nuget packages](https://github.com/huysentruitw?tab=repositories&q=entity&type=&language=) (depending on your EF version). It makes the mocking lot more easier.

Answer (score 21):

Moq relies on being able to create a proxy class that overrides properties. The `Context.Cafe` can't be overridden. Try declaring that property `virtual`.

```
public virtual IDbSet<Cafe> Cafe { get; set; }
```

Comment: cafe is currently setup like so -> public DbSet<Cafe> Cafe { get; set; } is IDbSet needed as well when declaring the property as virtual?

Comment: I get this error now when I changed it to virtual -> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: TestProject.Data.Context.
    Could not find a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @rey123: I don't think `IDbSet<>` is required: I just have better luck mocking interfaces than classes, which you're discovering here. Sounds like you'll either need to add a parameterless constructor to `Context` or stop trying to mock it. :-) Consider implementing an interface, and mocking that interface instead.

Comment: Is there any other way I can test public async Task<VersionResponse> Get(int cafeId) - since it seems to be using context so thought it would be best to try mock a context

Comment: Yeah, if `_context` is an injected interface (`IContext`), and `.Cafe` is on that interface, then you should be able to mock an `IContext`.

Comment: Yeah I'm running into quite a few errors so might try see if there's an alternative way to test this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mocking a concrete object you have no access to. Instead of mocking `DbSet`, use the interface so that Moq can implement it at runtime.

Instead of this...

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Cafe>>();
```

Do this...

```
var mockSet = new Mock<IDbSet<Cafe>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setup mock on **Set** method instead

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
```

in your case

```
var contextMock = new Mock<Context>();
contextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<Cafe>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got a Better way For Integration Tests
You can Use Transaction RollBack for this Type of Tests
in this way you can do what ever you want in Db and then every single movement in Db are back to last state of Before Running Tests

if you using Ef you can add this class to your Test Project and Enjoy it

```
public abstract class PersistTest<T> : IDisposable where T : DbContext, new()
{
    protected T DBContext;
    private TransactionScope scope;
    protected PersistTest()
    {
        scope = new TransactionScope();
        DBContext = new T();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        scope.Dispose();
        DBContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

this class help you to write better integration tests,

your test class should inherited from this abstract class and pass your context class as a instance of DbContext

and one more thing about your Codd you should seperate your Logic and DataAccess from each other

just define a interface Called ICofeeRepository and take your methods in it
Your Code Break the Single Responsibility principle

Your Service Should be Like

```
public class CoffeService
{
    //inject cafe repository ; _repo
    public async Task<VersionResponse> Get(int cafeid)
    {
        var cafe = _repo.FindById(cafeid);
        if (cafe == null)
            throw Exception("");
        //other wise .....
    }
}
```

and your Repository Should be Like

```
public interface ICafeRepository
{
    Cafe Get(int cafeid);
}
```

Comment: You want to mock DB, in memory sqlite for relation db or Mongo2Go for MongoDb, don't touch real DB